# how can I create displayName using bindable property?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I want to create one custom textbox. here i used two textbox, first one for firstName and second one for LatName. using custom textbox i want work both textbox functionality.I want to use both textbox for different display name how can i do that. Can I add displayName property in UI side means from textbox.html side for changes displayName for other textbox.

In short, first text error as it is, but second textbox error name "FIrstName is required" instead of "LastName is required" i want. is  this possible ?

I attached screen short.

## textbox.html

```
<input type="text" value.bind="myval & validate">
```

## textbox.ts

```
export class textbox {

  @bindable displayName: string = 'firstName';
}
ValidationRules
  .ensure('myval').displayName('first Name')
  .required()
  .on(textbox);
```

## app.html

```
<template>
<require from="./components/textbox"></require>

<textbox></textbox>
<textbox></textbox>
</template>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ga30.jpg)

Comment: Please be more specific. What is it you are actually asking?

Comment: I have changed question because previous question i want to need more research.

Answer (score 1):

Use a validation display name accessor, like so:

**textbox.ts**

```
ValidationRules
  .ensure('myval').displayName(t => t.displayName)
  .required()
  .on(textbox);
```

And set the display name for each textbox:

**app.html**

```
<textbox display-name="First Name"></jtextbox>
<textbox display-name="Last Name"></jtextbox>
```

Comment: not working. let's I add more information in question for understanding.

Comment: See my latest edit. You need to set the displayName attribute for each textbox. Note that you could leave the attribute off of the first textbox since it defaults to "First Name", but I think you wouldn't want a default in the general case.

Comment: not working again. is there any site where we can learn apart from aurelia.io ?